# Please explain why is the output of given python code is [1,[-1]] and not [1,[2]]?

Tags: python, list

```
x=[1,[2]]
y=list(x)
x[0]=-1
x[1][0] = -1
print(y)
```

I thought the answer would be [1,[2]] as the changes were made after declaring variable y but the output i get is [1,[-1]].
Please explain the reason.

Comment: @nonDucor - `list(x)` has made a copy of `x`; albeit, a *shallow* copy.

Answer (score 3):

When you assing y you are not making a new list, you are pointing to the same object as x. So when you update x, y is now pointing to the "new" version of x

edit-- @S3DEV pointed out that this answer is is not that precise,  list(x) has made a copy (new object) of x; albeit, a shallow copy. So it has made a copy of x, but not the second element of the list witch is an other list. y[1] is pointing to the same object that x[1] is pointing to.

Comment: In this case, no; this is incorrect.    `list(x)` has made a copy (new object) of `x`; albeit, a *shallow copy*.

Comment: To follow on from @S3DEV comment, `y[1]` is pointing to the same list as `x[1]`

Comment: … and `y[0]` is a new object.  So it’s really a mishmash of new objects (`y[0]`) and references (`y[1]`)